# Why doesn't iterate over a container accessed directly through std::optional<T>::value() work?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++20, stdoptional, range-based-loop

I'm trying to iterate over a `std::vector<X>` contained in a `struct T` that I access through a `std::optional<T>`. Contrary to my expectations, the behavior is different if I first store the `std::optional<T>` into a copy versus if I iterate it directly:

```
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// The rest is the same in both implementations    
struct Object
{
    std::string id;
    std::vector<SomeStructType> items;
};

Object readDataFile() { /*....*/ return {}; }
bool dataFileExists() { /*....*/ return true; }

std::optional<Object> getData()
{
    if (!dataFileExists()) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    Object obj = readDataFile();
    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    // Implementation 1 - works
    auto items = getData().value().items;
    for (auto const& item : items)
    {
        // will normally iterate over items
    }

    // Implementation 2 - for loop is skipped
    for (auto const& item : getData().value().items)
    {
        // this body will never execute
    }
}
```

I would expect those two to behave the same. Why does implementation **2** skip the for loop? `

The file read is the same in both cases, with `items.size() == 1`. I omitted some other `nullopt` checks and asserts in the provided code, but I don't expect them to be relevant.

Comment: Code always exists in some context. You should always provide code inside a function to provide such context. In this case you should provide [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635908/temporary-optional-in-the-range-based-for-loop-expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> would expect those two to behave the same. Why does implementation 2 skip the for loop?

In your second implementation `getData()` returns a temporary `std::optional<Object>` which will be destroyed end of the expression (in other words, even before the range-based for loop starts).

```
for (auto const &item : getData().value().items)
//                      ^^^^^^^^^ ---> temporary std::optional<Object>
{
}
```

The [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) thus holds the ranges of the invalid  `items`. Using this leads to your program's undefined behavior. In your case, the loop didn't get executed.

---

That being said, if the compiler warnings are turned on, you would have already been warned about it. For instance, [clang 15](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oq5aq94GK) with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -fsanitize=address,undefined` says:

```
<source>:25:29: warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
    for (auto const& item : getData().value().items)
                            ^~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
<source>:25:29: warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
    for (auto const& item : getData().value().items)
                            ^~~~~~~~~
//...
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7f1262400040 at pc 0x55ba03d4ae30 bp 0x7ffd89ca2a90 sp 0x7ffd89ca2a88
//...
```

---

You can increase the lifetime with some tweaks. See an example [mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635908/temporary-optional-in-the-range-based-for-loop-expression).

Comment: Thank you. I'm using MSVC and its code analysis didn't point this out ... Better switch to clang-tidy I guess!